# Resolvent Kernel of Volterra Equation

Tags: integral-equations

I need to find the resolvent kernel of
$\phi(x)=f(x)+\int\limits_0^x \sin(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$.

Differentiating both sides I get
$$ \phi'(x) = f'(x) + \int_0^x \cos(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt. $$

And now I am stuck.

I have also tried the resolvent kernel sum method, ie.
\begin{gather*}
  K(x,t) = K_1(x,t) = \sin(x-t) \\
  K_2(x,t) = \int_0^x K(x,s)\cdot K(s,t)\,ds = x\cos(x-t)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)\cos(x)
\end{gather*}
and so on...

Comment: No ! You are not allowed to differentiate in this way: the fact that variable $x$ is present also at one of the bounds of integration necessitates that you use a more general formula that you can find for example in the answer to the following question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223409).

Comment: try using $\phi''(x) = f''(x) + f(x)$