# taking differential of integral with function limit and CDF as integrator

Tags: integration, derivatives, probability-distributions

I have

$$\int_{-\bar{\lambda}}^{\lambda^{*}}\left(\frac{D-\rho_{F}\ell M-\rho_{A}\ell A}{\left(1-\rho_{F}\ell\right)D}-\tilde{\lambda}\right)dG(\tilde{\lambda})$$

where G is a continously increasing CDF on the interval $-\bar{\lambda},\bar{\lambda}$ and $\tilde{\lambda}$ is an IID random variable drawn from corresponding PDF to $G$ with mean 0. Finally, $\lambda^*=\frac{D-\rho_{F}\ell M-\rho_{A}\ell A}{\left(1-\rho_{F}\ell\right)D}$. I need to take FOC wrt the variables $M$, and $A$.

I am guessing to use the leibniz formula but am struggling with getting something "nice"

Comment: Behind the curtain is the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

Comment: Indeed, but I'm not sure it changes much here wrt. to the final derivation?

Comment: OK. I though it was one of your concerns. A little advice : simplify ! For example, I don't see the interest to keep the front fraction for the explanation of your issue...

Comment: Youre right. I will delete the fron constant :-)!

Comment: The role of $\lambda^*$ in $\int_{-\bar{\lambda}}^{\lambda^{*}}\left(\lambda^*-\tilde{\lambda}\right)dG(\tilde{\lambda})$ which is present at two places (upper bound and inside the parenthesis) isn't clear : is it a constant or a parameter that, sooner or later, will vary ? I think that, if you want to have answers, to have to make things clearer.

Comment: Besides, what do you mean by First Order Condition here ? Do you consider distributions of Poisson type for example ?

Comment: Maybe [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223409/how-to-find-the-derivative-of-an-integral-where-both-the-limit-and-the-integran) can be useful ?

Comment: thanks! It is indeed solved by the Leibniz rule